# Conv bias or not with Instance Normalization?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, batch-normalization

It is well known that Conv layers that are followed by BatchNorm ones should not have bias due to BatchNorm having a bias term.

Using InstanceNorm however, the statistics are instance-specific rather than batch-specific yet there are still are two learnable parameters $\gamma$ and $\beta$, where $\beta$ is a learnable bias.

Naturally, Conv layers followed by InstanceNorm layers should also not use bias.

Though some well-renowned implementations on github insist on using Conv bias when followed by InstanceNorm.

What's your take on this?

Answer (score 2):

I just found out why.
In pytorch it all depends on whether or not the affine parameter is set to True or False.

> affine – a boolean value that when set to True, this module has learnable affine parameters, initialized the same way as done for batch normalization. Default: False.

For InstanceNorm it defaults to False which is why people use conv bias with instance norm whereas with BatchNorm, affine defaults to True which explains why people don't use conv bias with BatchNorm

Answer (score 2):

Bias should not be used before InstanceNorm exactly as before BatchNorm. Whether you set affine to True or False, these layers first normalize the input, so any added bias is discarded.